# Azure Synapse: Can't drop column due to it has dependent statistics

Tags: statistics, azure-synapse

We use Azure Synapse Analytics. When trying to drop a column

```
ALTER table my_table drop COLUMN my_column
```

it says that:
*The statistics 'Stat_616f789ac8c54c449f7910cb3bcb3810' is dependent on column 'my_column'.*

But I had no luck in finding said stats to drop them:

```
select * from sys.stats where name like '%Stat%'
```

How can I determine and eliminate this annoying blocker?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple modification of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-statistics#determine-last-statistics-update) query to show the auto-created statistics for a table. Make the following changes:

```
where st.user_created = 0
      and sm.name = 'MY_SCHEMA_NAME'
      and tb.name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

Then drop the offending stats using the [DROP STATISTICS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-statistics-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) command.

Alternatively, turn off auto-statistics to avoid the creation of statistics you don't recognise.

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-statistics#automatic-creation-of-statistics).

Comment: Since writing this reply I've learned that a product change will be made shortly that automatically drops system-created statistics when an ALTER TABLE query is run against a table. Good news :)

Comment: Hi Ron, turning-off statistics is not the solution for me. The case that I don't see concerned statistics in sys.stats, and since your suggested query refers to this view it does not help unfortunately. . Hence I'm still confused how to determine where these stats exist to drop them further

Comment: @Alex did you find a solution to this? Started seeing the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately the only workaround for me is to drop/create table, basically not an issue on development stage, but will require backup in case of useful table data exist